# Подключение к labs.play-with-docker.com по ssh

Tags: docker, ssh

Проблема в том, что нужно достать приатный ключ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Заходим на сайт и запусаем сессию

Далее `cat .ssh/id_rsa`, нам выводится ключ.

Теперь у себя на компютере создаём файл с расширением key и вставляем в него приватный ключ.

Выполняем команду `ssh -i KAYNAME.key {то что указано на сайте в разделе SSH}`. Например `ssh -i doc.key ip172-18-0-52-bkd1u4ht0o8g0086u65g@direct.labs.play-with-docker.com`

Всё! Мы вошли!